# Undefined variables after subscribing for a promise in RxJS

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-components

I am trying to update a component variable in Angular using RxJS promise and using function `.then()` to update a local component property, but after executing, the value of the component property keeps undefined, why?

I'm trying to update the component's property like this:

**beautiful-layout.component.ts**

```
myComponentProperty: string;

logMyBeautifulMessage() {
  myPromiseFunction();
  console.log(this.myComponentProperty);
  // At this point, myComponentProperty keeps undefined.
}

myPromiseFunction() {
  this.myHttpService.findAll().toPromise().then(response => {
      this.myComponentProperty = response.helloMessage;
      console.log(this.myComponentProperty);
      // At this point, myComponentProperty has the value of 'Hello World!' as it should be.
    }
  );
}
```

Why the value of `myComponentProperty` keeps undefined event after executing a function that wait for a promise and set properly the property value?

Comment: The promise is an async operation. Your wrong assumption is, that the function waits for the promise. The `then()` is executed AFTER you log the property in `logMyBeautifulMessage`.

Comment: So it's better to use async/await declarations instead using `then()` function?

Comment: Yes, if you really want to wait you should create async methods `async logMyBeautifulMessage() { this.myComponentProperty = (await this.myHttpService.findAll().toPromise()).helloMessage; console.log(this.myComponentProperty); }`

Comment: Got it, I thought there was any way to do it using `then()` function, but I replaced it with async/await operations and is working fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using `.then()`, you could redo this like this.

```
myComponentProperty: string;

logMyBeautifulMessage() {
  myPromiseFunction().then(property => 
    console.log(`Updated property: ${property}`)
  );
}

myPromiseFunction() {
  return this.myHttpService.findAll().toPromise().then(response => {
    this.myComponentProperty = response.helloMessage;
    return this.myComponentProperty;
  });
}
```

This is saying: after my promise function has set the property, **then** print it to the console.